# Redirect virtual url to access different files inside sub directories

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, alias

I have a site `https://www.test.com` inside root which is `public_html` and I uploaded different files inside sub-directory that is  `https://www.test.com/sites/default/files/docs` is there any way to access all the files using this short url alias

```
https://www.test.com/mydocs/file1.pdf
https://www.test.com/mydocs/file2.docx
https://www.test.com/mydocs/file3.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure apache module `mod_rewrite` is on, add below code to .htaccess file, restart apache.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^mydocs/(.*) sites/default/files/docs/$1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I still couldn't access the actual file, The requested URL "/mydocs/readme.txt" was not found on this server. I can access that file with complete url

Comment: Have you restart apache? Can you post your .htaccess file?

Comment: I didn't restart apache, I have shared hosting, I think there is no need to restart apache for this change, here is the file,  please check the direct link I have added above your code at the very end of this file
https://www.military-divorce-guide.com/sites/default/files/docs/htaccess_0.txt

Comment: any solution please? @yip102011

Comment: I test the config on this [https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/). There are too rule in your file, some rules stop the process before it reaches this rule. I move this rule right below `RewriteEngine On` and it works.

Comment: This rule `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` stop everything after it.

Comment: your above line of code just redirect to the correct url alias which is sitename/mydocs/htaccess_0.txt
but I'm not able to access actual file located inside sitename/sites/all/default/files/docs
as I got this error The requested URL "/mydocs/htaccess_0.txt" was not found on this server.

Comment: My apology, I mix up the actual file location and requested url. I updated the code.

Comment: Thank you , you did it.

Comment: This htaccess file was in sub directory for my addon domain, how can I access directory of addon domain from main primary domain which inside public_html, both has separate htaccess file, above code works for the addon domain htaccess file, any code for htaccess code inside public_html to access addon domain directory files. thank you

Comment: I think you just need to add a rule that similar as this one to your primary domain htaccess file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186038/discussion-between-yip102011-and-web-dev).